# Atom: viewing a pdf

Tags: atom-editor

My pdf looks like:

[image]

How do I make it show the actual pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I loaded pdf-view from https://atom.io/packages/pdf-view and now when I open a pdf file i get it shown onscreen as a it's meant to be displayed.  There is also a package named pdf-view-Plus which claims to be better than pdf-view. Just load the package and you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Atom on his own cant read the PDF document as it is a binary file, in order to view the formatted document you must use a Atom package like https://atom.io/packages/pdf-view

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install some other extension as Atom can't read PDFs on it's own. You could use something such as https://atom.io/packages/pdf-view.